# Running Total - Python

Tags: python, output

The program below works as intended. It is designed to simply read multiple text files by throwing up a dialog box that will allow the user to select the text file to read, then it will output the findings in a new output file called "List_Of_Words.txt".

The problem I am having, and I cant seem to figure out, is that when the program reads multiple text files to read and appends to the output file, I cannot figure out how to make the output file also include a total count of words that it finds. For example, I read 3 text files, and it gives me the words it found in each text file, and next to each word is the number of times that word appears, but I also need it to tell me the total number of words it found from all text files it reads, at the bottom of the output file.

What I get when I run the program against 3 text files:

Document Name: C:/Python27/Abraham Lincoln - Emancipation Proclamation (January 1, 1863).txt

```
proclamation:   7
constitution:   1
people:   6
authority:   2
strong:   1
freedom:   3
rebellion:   7
mankind:   1
emancipation:   2
slaves:   3
```

Document Name: C:/Python27/Andrew Jackson - Second Inaugural Address (March 4, 1833).txt

```
leaders:   1
constitution:   2
liberty:   4
mankind:   1
society:   1
countrymen:   1
wisdom:   1
responsibility:   1
federal:   2
impoverished:   1
country:   3
happiness:   2
community:   1
world:   2
people:   9
citizens:   3
blessings:   1
contribute:   1
republic:   2
```

Document Name: C:/Python27/Gettysburg.txt

```
liberty:   1
nation:   5
world:   1
brave:   1
people:   4
freedom:   1
```

What I'm looking for at the end is " Total count of all words found based on each word:" + the word + frequency of word from all files

Here is the code for the program:

```
from sys import argv
import sys
from string import punctuation
from collections import *
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

keyWords = ['God', 'Nation', 'nation', 'USA', 'Creater', 'creater', 'Country', 'Almighty',
             'country', 'People', 'people', 'Liberty', 'liberty', 'America', 'Independence', 
             'honor', 'brave', 'Freedom', 'freedom', 'Courage', 'courage', 'Proclamation',
             'proclamation', 'United States', 'Emancipation', 'emancipation', 'Constitution',
             'constitution', 'Government', 'Citizens', 'citizens', 'love', 'Love', 'Strong', 
             'strong', 'Happiness', 'happiness', 'Dignity', 'dignity', 'Motivation', 'motivation',
             'Strength', 'strgenth', 'authority', 'rebellion', 'slave', 'slaves', 'contribute',
             'countrymen', 'leader', 'leaders', 'impoverished', 'community', 'society', 'republic',
             'democrat', 'democracy', 'wisdom', 'world', 'mankind', 'responsibility', 'blessing',
             'blessings', 'federal']

fileDict = {}

print "Do you know the location of the file(s)?"
answer = raw_input("> ")

if answer.lower()  == "yes":
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
elif answer.lower() == "no":
    print "\nPlease locate the file first before running program\n"
    print "Program will now close"
    sys.exit()

if file_path:
    print "Text file to import and read:", file_path
    print "\nReading file..."

    word_freq = {}  
    text_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    all_lines = text_file.readlines()
    text_file.close()

    print "\nFile read finished!\n"

    for line in all_lines:
        for word in line.split():
            word = word.strip(punctuation).lower()
            if word in word_freq:
                word_freq[word] += 1;
            else:
                word_freq[word] = 1;

    fileDict[file_path] = word_freq


print "Writing sum of results to: List_Of_Words.txt"

output_file = open("List_Of_Words.txt", "a")


for fileName in fileDict:
    output_file.write("\nDocument Name: %s\n\n" % (fileName))
    for word in fileDict[fileName]:
        if word in keyWords:
            output_file.write( "%s: %3d\n" % (word, word_freq[word]) )

output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep an additional dictionary mapping words to counts, and each time a word is encountered, update the count of the word.

Something like

```
wordCounts = {}
<some code>
wordCounts[wordEncountered] = wordCounts.get(wordEncountered,default=0) + 1
```

something like this?

```
wordCounts = {}
word = wordEncountered
wordCounts[wordEncountered] = wordCounts.get(wordEncountered,default=0) + 1
print wordCounts
```

Comment: before or after the output_file.close()

Comment: Declare that dictionary at the beginning of the file, then update it whenever you encounter/process a word. Finally, iterate through the dictionary and write the results to your file _before_ closing it.